# Receive data from Post request in TEST mode Django Rest

Tags: unit-testing, django-rest-framework, django-tests

how i can get token in Test mode if it generates after login

```
client = APIClient()
client.post('/api/login/', {'username': 'username', 'password': 'password'}, format='json')
```

and after request have to back response of Token key in json. Using requests to dev server works fine but how to use in TEST mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you django-rest-framework test cases. When test case runs it will create a new database so we do not have any data in the database.
After it will call method `setUp` to create required data to be used in test.

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

class AccountTests(APITestCase):

   def setUp(self):
       super(AccountTests, self).setUp()
       user = User.objects.create(user_name='username')
       user.set_password('password')
       user.save()
       self.token = Token.objects.create(user=user)

   def test_login(self):
      url = '/api/login/'
      data = {'username': 'username', 'password': 'password'}
      response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
      # key = response.json()['token']
      # self.assertEqual(key, self.token.key)
```